# CakePHP 3.0.4 and Invalid CSRF token

Tags: csrf, cakephp-3.0

I'm having a problem with CSRF component since I've updated to the last 3.0.4 CakePHP version yesterday. Looks like there is a security fix for previous versions so I decided to upgrade as soon as possibile, but since then I'm having this error when I try to login into my app:

```
Invalid CSRF token.
```

Strangely enough, I have seen a funny behavior while trying to figure out what is happening:

1) I went to my AppController.php, set the secure option to Csrf component to false, then I login -> it works

2) Set that option to true and login again -> it works

3) In (chrome) incognito mode, try to login from there -> it fails (invalid CSRF token)

4) After the incognito failure, try to login again from -not incognito mode- -> it works

Looking at the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html) I thought that enabling it and using the standard Form helper would be enough... do I need something else? Everything was working correctly with the 3.0.2 version I was using before.

Comment: I just baked a new app and did this, but could not reproduce your error. What do you think could be different?

Comment: Actually I really have no idea. If this can help, I'm developing this application since RC1 and I have continuously updated it until now... do you think it could be something related to one of my config files?

Comment: I've baked a new app using 3.0.4, merging my src and webroot folders but I'm facing the same problem.

Anyway, the _csrfToken looks correctly set in DebugKit's Request panel...

This is the whole error:

Invalid CSRF token.
Errore: The requested address '/sviluppo/users/login' was not found on this server.

Comment: possibly a cookie named `csrfToken` is not set or not correctly sent back to the server.

Comment: Maybe you are in the right direction. Actually, there is no cookies called csrfToken when csrf's secure option is set to true. If I set it to false the cookie is there.

Comment: I have found something. If I load the component as stated in the [CSRF documentation page](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html) it doesn't work. If I load it [this other way](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller) it works. So `$this->loadComponent('Csrf', ['secure' => true]);` doesn't work, while `$this->loadComponent('Csrf');` works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `secure` flag in t Csrf component means that the cookie will only be set if using a https (secure) connection. If the form is not generated and submitted over https, then it will block the attempt

Comment: Ok then this is why it was failing... I am still developing my app and there is no https. I think this should be explained more clearly in csrf component's documentation... anyway, thanks a lot!